# Displaying items from a database in a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I'm using ado.net to display date from an sql database. Here is the below code:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YoutubeConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select CityId, CityName, Country from Youtube", con);
        con.Open();
        drpCountries.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        drpCountries.DataTextField = "CityName";
        drpCountries.DataValueField = "CityId";
        drpCountries.DataBind();

    }
}
  }
```

Every time I run this I get an error saying "Invalid object name Youtube".

Thanks

Dan

Comment: Is youtube the name of your table?

Comment: That mean you haven't table `Youtube` in DB which accessed by connection string `YoutubeConnectionString1`.

Comment: Is "Youtube" a table in a database specified by YoutubeConnectionString1?

Comment: This means `Youtube` table or view cannot be found in the db. Check that it exists in the db and that the connection string points to the right db.

Comment: yea youtube is the name of the database. heres my connectionstring connectionStrings>
        <add name="YoutubeConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=DANNY-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Youtube;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select CityId, CityName, Country from Youtube <-- this is the table where you are getting CityId, CityName and Country from. What is this table called? It's not YouTube.

Comment: Okay, good. You should post your answer just so others that come across this may see.